# Getting "docker: invalid reference format." when running docker-deploy-hdp30.sh

Tags: docker, hdp

I am trying to set up the HDP3 docker sandbox.  I run the deploy script.  The container starts successfully, but during the post deploy scripts, it ends with "docker: invalid reference format.".  The container is running, but only a few ports are mapped at this point.

Tried to find some answers here, but I don't see this exact issue

Here is the entire output:

```
+ registry=hortonworks
+ name=sandbox-hdp
+ version=3.0.1
+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy
+ proxyVersion=1.0
+ flavor=hdp
+ echo hdp
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
70799bbf2226: Pull complete 
40963917cdad: Pull complete 
3fe9adbb8d7e: Pull complete 
ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pull complete 
7ea5917732c0: Pull complete 
2d951411620c: Pull complete 
f4c5e354e7fd: Pull complete 
22ffa6ef360f: Pull complete 
2060aa0f3751: Pull complete 
ca01ba34744d: Pull complete 
83326dded077: Pull complete 
eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete 
bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete 
500cc770c4bd: Pull complete 
0cb1decd5474: Pull complete 
b9591f4b6855: Pull complete 
f28e56086127: Pull complete 
e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete 
ec77967d2166: Pull complete 
4fdcae170114: Pull complete 
6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete 
6a6ecc232709: Pull complete 
ea845898ff50: Pull complete 
02135573b1bf: Pull complete 
cb0176867cd8: Pull complete 
3c08321268fd: Pull complete 
82e82a97c465: Pull complete 
8aaaa48ed101: Pull complete 
74b321ac2ac5: Pull complete 
569da02c0a66: Pull complete 
af40820407ef: Pull complete 
Digest:           sha256:7b767af7b42030fb1dd0f672b801199241e6bef1258e3ce57361edb779d95921
Status: Downloaded newer image for hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy
Digest:     sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e
Status: Image is up to date for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'
+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'
+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
++ docker images
++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ version=3.0.1
+ docker network create cda
+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-    hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-   hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
1eb02f20456a5be1d553bb7dc67e1db1203edfcc8b54d8a0bc3c5e0850a5e079
+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'
 Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait
+ sleep 2
+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*;     systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'
+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-    deploy-script.sh
+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-    proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ uname
+ grep MINGW
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being caused by the fact that I'm running the script from a directory path that has a space in it, and there is a generated shell script that runs a proxy container and uses volume mappings using the current path.  The script does not take into account the spaces.  Here is the lines that get generated:

docker run --name sandbox-proxy --network=cda \
-v /Users/iklein99/OneDrive - hibu/HDP/HDP_3/assets/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
-v /Users/iklein99/OneDrive - hibu/HDP/HDP_3/sandbox/proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
-v /Users/iklein99/OneDrive -    hibu/HDP/HDP_3/sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d:/etc/nginx/conf.stream.d .  ...

The spaces in the file path are causing the issue.  The script doesn't put the path in quotes or escape the spaces.  I'm modifying the sed script to handle this.